# Webkit turning "#" into %23 causing 404 errors?

Tags: javascript, ajax, webkit, http-status-code-404

I'm just building a simple ajax site but running into a problem in safari and chrome. I'm just creating a simple redirect if the user goes to a page i.e.

```
"/blog"
```

they would be redirected to

```
"/#/blog"
```

code :

```
url = window.location.pathname

if(url != "/") {
   window.location.pathname = "/#" + url
}
```

This is working great in FireFox but unfortunatly webkit browsers are turning the "#" into a "%23" and giving a 404, for example:

```
"/%23/blog"
```

How can I prevent this?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting pathname, which, by definition, does not include the hash.  Webkit is trying to fix that for you (Firefox just made a better guess of what you wanted). Try this:

```
window.location = '/#/blog';
```

Answer (score 2):

`pathname` refers to everything after the host, and before the query string and hash.  Consider this instead:

```
window.location.hash = window.location.pathname;
window.location.pathname = "/";
```

I'm not exactly sure which browser(s) are implementing the JavaScript spec correctly, but WebKit's behavior seems correct to me.

Comment: but surely when the page reloads to "/" it will remove the hash?

Comment: @Alex not on chromium... not sure about other browsers, but generally the hash is preserved

Comment: Using your method it goes from "/blog" => "/blog#/blog" => to "/"

Comment: Actually it might be some of my pages logic which is causing that!

Comment: If you don't change the pathname, it *won't* reload.

Comment: @Malvolio OP needs the pathname to change to meet his specification; the pathname should always be "/"

Comment: So this seems to work in chrome but FireFox doesn't keep the hash. I'll just have to use different methods for each browser I suppose.

Comment: @alex_c Yeh I did and still had the same problem! The solution was Malvolio's - window.location = "/#" + url. Thanks though!